# ASP.NET Identity not being able to login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am working to give an admin the option of adding new users to my website, using ASP.NET Identity.

My idea is that I have a link in my layout that redirects me to the account/register view

```
if (User.IsInRole(RoleName.IsAdmin))
{ //this is just for the admin
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">                        
        //other links
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Add assistant", "Register", "Account")</li>
    </ul>
}
```

This is my account/register action, where I add users to the role "IsAssistant".

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = RoleName.IsAdmin)]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.FirstName, Email = model.Email,kclusername=model.kclusername,
        FirstName=model.FirstName,LastName=model.LastName};
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var role = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>();
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(role);
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(RoleName.IsAssistant));
            await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, RoleName.IsAssistant);
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
            UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

When I create a new user, I am redirected and sign in as the new user. But when I try to log in again, I can not, and I receive a message "invalid login attempt".
I did not modify the login action:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

What is wrong? Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: try to remove this line `await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);` this should prevent you from signing in as the newly registered user

Comment: Since you call `UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync` (but you don't do anything with it) in the register function, that implies users need to confirm their email address, is that true? Does the user entry in the database have that flag set to false? Can you log in if you manually set it to true?

Comment: Anton Toshik, I tried it before, but there is an invalid user attempt message still

Comment: DavidG, the confirm email is set to false, however this problem happend when I made the register action available for the admin

Comment: for some reason, when I access the register action with a loged user I have this problem

Comment: I don't understand why `rolemanager.CreateAsync` is called for each new user. Once a role is created, you shouldn't need to recreate it.

Comment: Tim, maybe I should delete that line...however that line is not causing my problem.The code works fine if I do not add users as admin(register a user as per default in asp.net mvc project). The problem occurs when I hit the action from my admin account